# Need help - Getting an error: xrealloc: subst.c:4072: cannot reallocate 1073741824 bytes (0 bytes allocated)

Tags: linux, bash, variables, unix, limit

Checking if anybody else had the similar issue.

Code in the shell script:

```
  ## Convert file into Unix format first.
  ## THIS is IMPORTANT.
  #####################
  dos2unix "${file}" "${file}";
  #####################

  ## Actual DB Change
  db_change_run_op="$(ssh -qn ${db_ssh_user}@${dbserver} "sqlplus $dbuser/${pswd}@${dbname} <<ENDSQL
@${file}
ENDSQL
")";
```

Summary:

1. From a shell script (on a SunOS source server) I'm running a sqlplus session via ssh on a target machine to run a .sql script.

2. Output of this target ssh session (running sqlplus) is getting stored in a variable within the shell script. Variable name: **db_change_run_op** (as shown above in the code snapshot).

3. Most of the .sql scripts (that the variable "${file}" stores) that I'm running, shell script runs it fine and returns me the output of the .sql file (ran on target server via ssh from source server) provided, if the .sql file contains something which doesn't take much time to complete -or generates reasonable amount of output log/lines.

for ex: Let's assume if .sql I want to run does the following, then it runs fine.

```
select * from database123;
udpate table....
alter table..
insert ....
...some procedure .... which doesn't take much time to create....
...some more sql commands which complete..within few minutes to an hour....
```

4. Now, the issue I'm facing is:

Let's assume I have a .sql file where a single select command from a table have couple of hundred thousands - upto 1-5millions of lines i.e.

```
select * from database321;
```

assume the above generates the above bullet 4 condition.

In this case, I'm getting the following error message thrown by the shell script (running on the source server).

**Error:**

*./db_change_load.sh: xrealloc: subst.c:4072: cannot reallocate 1073741824 bytes (0 bytes allocated)*

**My questions:**
1. Did the .sql script complete - I assume yes. But, how can I get the output LOG file of the .sql file generated on the target server directly. If this can be done, then I won't need the variable to hold the output of whole ssh session sqlplus command and then create a log file on source server by doing [ echo "${db_change_run_op}" > sql.${file}.log ] way.

1. I assume the error is coming as the output or no. of lines generated by the ssh session i.e. by the sqlplus is so big that it can't fit Unix/Linux BASH variable's limit and thus, xrealloc error.

Please advise if on the above 2 questions if you have any experience or how can i solve this.

I assume, I'll try using " | tee /path/on.target.ssh.server/sql.${file}.log" soon after << ENDSQL or final close of ENDSQL (here doc keyword), wondering if that would work or not..

Comment: You seem to have a good understanding of the basics of your problem. The `xrealloc` error is almost certainly the result of a 'too-large' result set being returned. (given the exact txt of the error msg you've included). For the problem case, you don't really want millions of rows back to store if the variable, do you? So what is the question, how to get back a reasonable stat msg OR how to get back all that data and store into a variable? Are you "reusing" that code in a for loop, executing a list of sql cmds? If so, you'll have to make 2+ diff loops, 1 to handle normal, 2+ for special case

Comment: To Answer your question: I dont want miliions of rows in general but i was trying to hit this case where i can reach # of lines of sql output that can impact how the shell script would work using that db_change_.. variable. I'm not using the variable in the for loop so it's not the case where var=$var-$newvar etc.

Answer (score 0):

OK. got it working. No more store stuff in a var and then echo $var to a file.

Luckily, I had a same mount point on both source and target server i.e. if I go to /scm on source and on target, the mount (df -kvh .) shows same output for Share/NAS mount value.

> Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
>   ServerNAS02:/vol/vol1/scm   700G   560G   140G    81%    /scm

Now, instead of using the variable to store the whole output of ssh session calling sqlplus session, all I did is was to create a file on the remote server using the following code.

```
  ## Actual DB Change
  #db_change_run_op="$(ssh -qn ${pdt_usshu_dbs}@${dbs} "sqlplus $dbu/${pswd}@$dbn <<ENDSQL | tee "${sql_run_output_file}".ssh.log
#set echo off
#set echo on
#set timing on
#set time on
#set serveroutput on size unlimited
#@${file}
#ENDSQL
#")";



ssh -qn ${pdt_usshu_dbs}@${dbs} "sqlplus $dbu/${pswd}@$dbn <<ENDSQL | tee "${sql_run_output_file}".ssh.log
set echo off
set echo on
set timing on
set time on
set serveroutput on size 1000000
@${file}
ENDSQL
"
```

seems like unlimited doesn't work in 11g so I had to use the 1000000 value (these small sql cmds help to show command with its output, show clock time for each output line etc).

But basically, in the above code, I'm calling the ssh command directly without using a variable="$(.....)" way.. and after the <

Even if I wouldn't have the same mount, I could have tee'd the output to a file on the remote server path (which is not available from source server) but atleast I can see upto what level the .sql command completed or generated output as now output is going directly to a file on remote server and Unix/Linux doesn't care much about the file size until there's no space left.

Comment: BTW, the following will save someone's smile. Run SSH command with "-o ServerAliveInterval=60" option otherwise, connection will reset and the automated script which is calling ssh to remote server, will never finish.

Comment: ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 username@domain.com

Comment: If you are on SunOS, then you might not have OpenSSH. See what version "ssh -v" shows. Btw, running ssh session using "nohup" would help in NOT getting "connection reset" issue from source server connection to target/remote server.

Comment: seems like nohup didn't help. I still see connection reset. instead of running ssh with sqlplus from srouce to target server, i'll call a script on target using ssh from source and wait for the PID of that script (to run sqlplus on target server) to finish